# wso2 conversion, xml to json conversion

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I am completely new to wso2 and I need to change my given input request xml to json and hit this to an adapter and get the response back in json and then in xml. How is this possible??

I am using wso2 integration studio for the development.

```
<Request>
<requestId><![CDATA[11111111111111111]]></requestId>
<timeStamp><![CDATA[2019/12/25 12:12:12]]> </timeStamp>
<msisdn> <![CDATA[888]]></msisdn>
<keyWord><![CDATA[TEST_API]]></keyWord>
<dataSet>
<param>
<id><![CDATA[first_id]]></id>
<value><![CDATA[12310209842396]]></value>
</param>
<param>
<id><![CDATA[second_id]]></id>
<value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
</param>
</dataSet>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mediation sequence, you can use the messageType property to indicate that the message should be converted to JSON when sending it to your adapter. And in the return phase, you can use the messageType property again to convert the message to XML.

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api name="toJson" context="/tojson" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" />
            <send>
                 <endpoint key="adapter"/>   
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2" />
            <send />
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: can you explain this process?? I am completely new into this. How can i create this mediation sequence??

Comment: I have edited my answer with a sample. Check it. If you need more help with playing around with the Studio, checkout this blog https://medium.com/think-integration/the-love-story-of-integration-studio-and-micro-integrator-7e10a8012f7f

Comment: so we need to create an adapter also, right?? how can i create an adapter using wso2 ??or should i create a normal servlet for this??

Comment: I just referred to the backend endpoint as the adapter (Like you asked in the question). You can use any endpoint there. (HTTP, JMS, RabbitMQ). For an HTTP example look at the above blog I shared.